# Is there any automated translation between Ido and Esperanto?

Tags: translation

Some time ago, the [Distributed Language Translation project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_Language_Translation) used Esperanto as an intermediate language. The project leveraged the regularity of Esperanto, to translate from one language to another by first automatically translating the source language into Esperanto and then the Esperanto into the target language. That raises the question of (bidirectional, because why not?) automatic translation between Esperanto and Ido. Given that the two languages are about as close as it's possible for two distinct languages to be, does anything like this exist? If not, are there any extensible automatic translation platforms which would make adding this language pair straightforward?

Answer (score 1):

Probably not, as Ido has just a few thousand users.

I'm aware about the DLT-project, as our local group translated a book for it.
A few years later the BBC-worldservice told me there was a similar project using Aymara as in-between language

Answer (score 0):

***Proposal for a new Project** (should there be none)*

That indeed should be a doable project, and the smaller community of Ido would certainly benefit from it. And Esperanto can use more translated text too (I am esperantist).

I hope translation in both directions is considered (possibly with different quality at first).

Unfortunately I would personally favor a project in Java - yes programming languages have their own competition. For TM, NLP and so on. A nicely documented & declarative system would be nice.

Comment: Meanwhile I have some working code, a **JavaFX application**. 1. It is nice. 2. It was created piecewise, intermittently - not well designed, but readable. 3. Grammatical analysis would be my next step, as without that the translation is insufficient.

Comment: The results are that indeed a grammatical transform is needed. The used grammar library was too circumstantial. Momentarily I do nothing.